# How to generate column that calculate with its predecessor value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

For example

```
Amount   ReceivedAmount   PendingAmount
---------------------------------------
 1000         400             600       
  600         400             200
```

How to I get (600) value in `Amount` column?

The table structure is

```
1. BillID,Amount,Date from table1
```

and

```
2. BillReceive,ReceiveDate,ReceivedAmount from table2
```

Received Amount Can be multiple time, I want pending amount from `(Amount - SUM(ReceivedAmount))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to fist join your tables `table 1` and `table 2`( below I did that in CTE). And then do a self join of the above result to get cumulative values.

<kbd>**[See working demo](https://rextester.com/PYHA49563)**</kbd>

```
 ; with cte as 
(
 select 
     billid, 
     amount,
     receivedamount, 
     r=row_number() over (partition by t1.billid order by ReceiveDate asc)
 from
  table1 t1 join table2 t2
      on t1.billid=t2.BillReceive
 )

 select 
   amount=max(c1.amount)+max(c1.receivedamount)-sum(c2.receivedamount),
   receivedamount=max(c1.receivedamount),
   pendingamount=max(c1.amount)-sum(c2.receivedamount)
 from 
   cte c1 left join cte c2 
      on c2.r<=c1.r and c2.billid=c1.billid
 group by c1.billid,c1.r
```